Where & why variable $fixletID is missing?
I have below code to run some automation work based on various items, I keep expending & testing it without clearly the PS ISE variable cache and when I try to run this script using task scheduler it failed, I tried it directly from ps it failed, after looking into logs was able to find the problem script is not able to retain the $fixletid & $exemptionrequest variable.
Major failure is where this script querying for $sitename using $fixletID, now since somehow fixletid is missing its failing the whole process.
Please review & guide, how to fix it.
//script is below.
# Define paths and variables
$exemptionRequestsFolder = "E:\BES Tools\Exemption"
$exemptionRequestsSubFolder = "E:\BES Tools\Exemption\Exemption_Requests"
$masterXmlPath = "E:\BES Tools\Exemption\Master_Exemption_Push.xml"
$masterSpecificTargetXmlPath = "E:\BES Tools\Exemption\Master_Exemption_Push_Specific_Target.xml"
$logFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $exemptionRequestsFolder -ChildPath "Logs"
$username = $env:BFX_API_U
$password = $env:BFX_API_P
$serverURL = 'https://my.server.com:52311'
$iemcli = "E:\Program Files (x86)\BigFix Enterprise\BES Server\IEM CLI\iem.exe"
$loginArgs = @("login", "--server=$serverURL", "--user=$username", "--password=$password")

# Initialize list for created XML files
$createdChildXmlFiles = @()

# Function to write log entries with timestamp
function Write-Log {
    param (
        [string]$Message
    )

    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    "$timestamp $Message" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logFilePath
}

# Define Replace-TextInFiles function
function Replace-TextInFiles {
    param (
        [string]$directoryPath,
        [string]$searchText,
        [string]$replaceText
    )

    # Get all text files in the directory
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -Filter *.txt -Recurse

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        try {
            $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
            if ($fileContent -match $searchText) {
                $updatedContent = $fileContent -replace [regex]::Escape($searchText), $replaceText
                $updatedContent | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8
                Write-Log "Updated file: $($file.FullName)"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Log "Error occurred while updating file: $($file.FullName). Error: $_"
        }
    }
}

# Create Logs folder if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $logFolderPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $logFolderPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

# Create a timestamped log file for the entire script execution
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
$logFilePath = Join-Path -Path $logFolderPath -ChildPath "$timestamp.log"

# Check if any file contains "Pending item"
$pendingItemFound = $false
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $exemptionRequestsSubFolder -Directory

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Filter *.txt

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
        if ($fileContent -match "Pending item") {
            $pendingItemFound = $true
            break
        }
    }

    if ($pendingItemFound) {
        break
    }
}

if (-not $pendingItemFound) {
    Write-Log "No files containing 'Pending item' found. Exiting script."
    exit
}

# Check if FixletID or ExemptionRequest in pending files match with completed files
$pendingFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $exemptionRequestsSubFolder -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Where-Object { (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -match "Pending item" }
$completedFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $exemptionRequestsSubFolder -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Where-Object { (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -match "Completed" }

foreach ($pendingFile in $pendingFiles) {
    $pendingFileContent = Get-Content -Path $pendingFile.FullName -Raw
    $pendingFixletID = if ($pendingFileContent -match "FixletID,(\d+)") { $matches[1] } else { $null }
    $pendingExemptionRequest = if ($pendingFileContent -match "ExemptionRequest,(\w+)") { $matches[1] } else { $null }

    if ($pendingFixletID -or $pendingExemptionRequest) {
        Write-Log "Found 'Pending item' file: $($pendingFile.FullName), FixletID: $pendingFixletID, ExemptionRequest: $pendingExemptionRequest"

        foreach ($completedFile in $completedFiles) {
            $completedFileContent = Get-Content -Path $completedFile.FullName -Raw
            $completedFixletID = if ($completedFileContent -match "FixletID,(\d+)") { $matches[1] } else { $null }
            $completedExemptionRequest = if ($completedFileContent -match "ExemptionRequest,(\w+)") { $matches[1] } else { $null }

            if ($completedFixletID -or $completedExemptionRequest) {
                Write-Log "Found 'Completed' file: $($completedFile.FullName), FixletID: $completedFixletID, ExemptionRequest: $completedExemptionRequest"

                if (($pendingFixletID -and $completedFixletID -and $pendingFixletID -eq $completedFixletID) -or
                    ($pendingExemptionRequest -and $completedExemptionRequest -and $pendingExemptionRequest -eq $completedExemptionRequest)) {
                    Write-Log "Matching completed file found for pending file: $($pendingFile.FullName) against completed file: $($completedFile.FullName). Exiting script."
                    exit
                }
            } else {
                Write-Log "No FixletID or ExemptionRequest found in 'Completed' file: $($completedFile.FullName)"
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Log "No FixletID or ExemptionRequest found in 'Pending item' file: $($pendingFile.FullName)"
    }
}

Write-Log "No matching completed files found for pending items. Continuing script execution."

# Delete old XML files (except master XML files) at the beginning
$masterXmlPaths = @($masterXmlPath, $masterSpecificTargetXmlPath)
$allXmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $exemptionRequestsFolder -Filter "*.xml"

foreach ($xmlFile in $allXmlFiles) {
    if (-not ($masterXmlPaths -contains $xmlFile.FullName)) {
        try {
            Remove-Item -Path $xmlFile.FullName -Force
            Write-Log "Deleted XML file: $($xmlFile.FullName)"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Log "Failed to delete XML file: $($xmlFile.FullName). Error: $_"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Log "Skipped deletion for master XML file: $($xmlFile.FullName)"
    }
}

# Login to BigFix server
try {
    # BigFix Server login
    Write-Log "Attempting to login to BigFix Server..."

    $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    $null = Start-Process -FilePath $iemcli -ArgumentList $loginArgs -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput $tempFile

    $output = Get-Content -Path $tempFile

    if ($output -match "Successfully") {
        Write-Log "Login successful."
    } else {
        Write-Log "Login failed. Exiting execution."
        exit
    }

    Write-Log "Command output:"
    Write-Log $output
}
catch {
    Write-Log "Error occurred during login: $_"
    exit
}
finally {
    Remove-Item -Path $tempFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

# List of known sitenames and their corresponding relevance expressions
$sitenamesRelevance = @{
   "ABC_macOS"        = "computer name = 'ABC' AND mac of operating system AND ((not exists setting '#Fixlet_ID#' of client) OR ((not exists value of it) OR (value of it does not equal (('#Exemption_Request#') as string))) of setting '#Fixlet_ID#' of client)"
    "ABC_RHEL7"        = "computer name = 'ABC' AND (exists match (regex 'Red Hat Enterprise (Client|Server|Workstation) 7') of name of operating system) AND ((not exists setting '#Fixlet_ID#' of client) OR ((not exists value of it) OR (value of it does not equal (('#Exemption_Request#') as string))) of setting '#Fixlet_ID#' of client)"
    "ABC_RHEL8"        = "computer name = 'ABC' AND (exists match (regex 'Linux Red Hat Enterprise\s*(Client|Server|Workstation|Linux)?\s*8') of name of operating system) AND ((not exists setting '#Fixlet_ID#' of client) OR ((not exists value of it) OR (value of it does not equal (('#Exemption_Request#') as string))) of setting '#Fixlet_ID#' of client)"
    "ABC_Windows10"    = "computer name = 'ABC' AND name of operating system = 'Win10' AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows11"    = "computer name = 'ABC' AND name of operating system = 'Win11' AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2012"  = "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2012') of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2016"  = "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2016' and product type of it != nt domain controller product type) of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2016DC"= "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2016' and product type of it = nt domain controller product type) of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2019"  = "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2019' and product type of it != nt domain controller product type) of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2019DC"= "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2019' and product type of it = nt domain controller product type) of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2022"  = "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2022' and product type of it != nt domain controller product type) of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
    "ABC_Windows2022DC"= "computer name = 'ABC' AND ((name of it = 'Win2022' and product type of it = nt domain controller product type) of operating system) AND (not exists key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry OR not exists value whose (name of it as string as lowercase contains '#Exemption_Request#' as lowercase) of key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\#Fixlet_ID#' of native registry)"
}

# Initialize the normalized known sitenames array (to lower case)
$normalizedSitenames = $sitenamesRelevance.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim().ToLower()
}

# Verify the initialization of the $sitenames array
if ($sitenamesRelevance.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Log "The known sitenames array is empty, please check initialization."
} else {
    Write-Log "Initial known sitenames: $($sitenamesRelevance.Keys -join ', ')"
    Write-Log "Normalized known sitenames: $($normalizedSitenames -join ', ')"
}

# Check for pending FixletID before assigning to $fixletID
if (-not $pendingFixletID) {
    Write-Log "The pendingFixletID variable is empty or null."
} else {
    # Storing $pendingFixletID as $FixletID
    $fixletID = $pendingFixletID
    Write-Log "Using pending FixletID: $fixletID"
}


# Logic to get the sitename
Write-Log "Querying sitename for FixletID $fixletID"
$query = "(name of site of bes fixlet whose (id of it = $fixletID))"

# Execute the query to get the site name
$outputFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
try {
    Start-Process -FilePath $iemcli -ArgumentList "get query --relevance=`"$query`"" -RedirectStandardOutput $outputFile -NoNewWindow -Wait

    # Read the output from the temporary file
    $output = Get-Content $outputFile -Raw

    # Parse the XML result to extract the site name
    [xml]$xmlResult = $output
    $sitename = $xmlResult.BESAPI.Query.Result.Answer.'#text'

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sitename)) {
         Write-Log "Failed to get the sitename. Output was empty."
         Exit 1
    }

    Write-Log "Sitename for FixletID $fixletID is $sitename"

    # Normalize the extracted sitename by converting to lower case and removing spaces
    $normalizedSitename = ($sitename -replace '\s', '').Trim().ToLower()
    Write-Log "Normalized extracted sitename: $normalizedSitename"

    # Ensure final known sitenames array is case-insensitive and normalized
    $finalNormalizedSitenames = $normalizedSitenames | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Trim().ToLower()
    }
    Write-Log "Final normalized known sitenames: $($finalNormalizedSitenames -join ', ')"

    # Check for matching sitename and retrieve the corresponding relevance
    if ($finalNormalizedSitenames -contains $normalizedSitename) {
        $global:Relevance = $sitenamesRelevance.Get_Item($sitename)
        Write-Log "Sitename match found & matching site is $sitename"
        Write-Log "Global Relevance for $sitename : $global:Relevance"
    } else {
        Write-Log "No match found for sitename $sitename"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Log "An error occurred: $_"
} finally {
    # Clean up temporary file
    Remove-Item $outputFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

 # Replace single quotes with double quotes
    $global:Relevance = $global:Relevance -replace "'", '"'

   # Function to create child XML using the specified master XML path
function Create-ChildXml {
    param (
        [string]$masterXmlPath,
        [string]$fixletID,
        [string]$exemptionRequest,
        [string]$childXmlFilePath,
        [string[]]$devicesList
 
    )

   Write-Log "Inside Create-ChildXml function"
    Write-Log "Relevance received: $global:Relevance"
    
    # Check if $global:Relevance has an unexpected or invalid value
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($global:Relevance) -or $global:Relevance -eq "Unexpected Value") {
        Write-Log "Exiting script: Invalid or unexpected relevance received: $global:Relevance"
        exit 1 # You can adjust the exit code as needed
    }
    
    Write-Log "Creating XML with FixletID: $fixletID and ExemptionRequest: $exemptionRequest for sitename: $sitename and Relevance: $global:Relevance"

    $childXmlContent = Get-Content -Path $masterXmlPath -Raw -Encoding UTF8
    $childXmlContent = $childXmlContent -replace "#Relevance#", $Relevance
    $childXmlContent = $childXmlContent -replace "#Fixlet_ID#", $fixletID
    $childXmlContent = $childXmlContent -replace "#Exemption_Request#", $exemptionRequest
    

    if ($devicesList) {
        $computerNameTemplate = '<ComputerName>{0}</ComputerName>'
        $computerNameElements = $devicesList | ForEach-Object { $computerNameTemplate -f $_ }
        $computerNames = $computerNameElements -join "`n"
        $childXmlContent = $childXmlContent -replace "#computername#", $computerNames
    }

    $childXmlDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($childXmlFilePath)
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $childXmlDirectory)) {
        New-Item -Path $childXmlDirectory -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    Set-Content -Path $childXmlFilePath -Value $childXmlContent -Encoding UTF8
    Write-Log "Child XML file created: $childXmlFilePath"
    $global:createdChildXmlFiles += $childXmlFilePath    
}
# Processing logic for each folder
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Write-Log "Processing folder: $($folder.FullName)"
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Filter *.txt

    $pendingItemFound = $false

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
        Write-Log "Checking file $($file.FullName)"
        if ($fileContent -match "Pending item") {
            $pendingItemFound = $true
            Write-Log "File $($file.FullName) contains 'Pending item'."
            break
        }
    }

    if (-not $pendingItemFound) {
        Write-Log "Skipping folder $($folder.FullName) because no file contains 'Pending item'."
        continue
    }

    # Process files
    $targetAllDevicesFile = $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "^TargetAllDevices_" }
    $targetDevicesListFile = $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "^TargetDevicesList_" }
    $fixletFile = $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "^\d{8}-\d{4}.txt$" }

    if ($targetAllDevicesFile -and $targetDevicesListFile -and $fixletFile) {
        $allDevicesContent = Get-Content -Path $targetAllDevicesFile.FullName
        $devicesListContent = Get-Content -Path $targetDevicesListFile.FullName
        $fixletContent = Get-Content -Path $fixletFile.FullName

        # Log without showing file content
        Write-Log "Processing files in folder $($folder.FullName)"

        $allDevicesYes = $allDevicesContent -match "YES"
        $allDevicesNo = $allDevicesContent -match "NO"

        Write-Log "AllDevices YES: $allDevicesYes"
        Write-Log "AllDevices NO: $allDevicesNo"

        if ($allDevicesYes) {
            # Use Master_Exemption_Push.xml
            $fixletID = $null
            $exemptionRequest = $null
            foreach ($line in $fixletContent -split "`n") {
                if ($line -match 'FixletID,(.+)') {
                    $fixletID = $matches[1].Trim()
                }
                elseif ($line -match 'ExemptionRequest,(.+)') {
                    $exemptionRequest = $matches[1].Trim()
                }
            }

            if ($fixletID -and $exemptionRequest) {
                $childXmlFileName = "Child_Exemption_Push_$($folder.Name).xml"
                $childXmlFilePath = Join-Path -Path $exemptionRequestsFolder -ChildPath $childXmlFileName
                Create-ChildXml -masterXmlPath $masterXmlPath -fixletID $fixletID -exemptionRequest $exemptionRequest -childXmlFilePath $childXmlFilePath -devicesList $null
            }
        }
        elseif ($allDevicesNo) {
            # Use Master_Exemption_Push_Specific_Target.xml
            $devicesList = @()
            $startAdding = $false
            foreach ($line in $devicesListContent -split "`n") {
                if ($startAdding) {
                    $devicesList += $line.Trim()
                }
                elseif ($line -match "Pending item") {
                    $startAdding = $true
                }
            }

            $fixletID = $null
            $exemptionRequest = $null
            foreach ($line in $fixletContent -split "`n") {
                if ($line -match 'FixletID,(.+)') {
                    $fixletID = $matches[1].Trim()
                }
                elseif ($line -match 'ExemptionRequest,(.+)') {
                    $exemptionRequest = $matches[1].Trim()
                }
            }

            if ($fixletID -and $exemptionRequest -and $devicesList.Count -gt 0) {
                $childXmlFileName = "Child_Exemption_Push_Specific_Target_$($folder.Name).xml"
                $childXmlFilePath = Join-Path -Path $exemptionRequestsFolder -ChildPath $childXmlFileName
                Create-ChildXml -masterXmlPath $masterSpecificTargetXmlPath -fixletID $fixletID -exemptionRequest $exemptionRequest -childXmlFilePath $childXmlFilePath -devicesList $devicesList
            }
        }
    }
}

# Post the created child XML files
foreach ($xmlFile in $createdChildXmlFiles) {
    try {
        Write-Log "Posting XML file to BigFix Server: $($xmlFile)"
        
        # Construct the arguments
        $postArgs = @("post", $xmlFile, "actions")
        
        # Execute the command
        $postOutput = & $iemcli @postArgs
        
        Write-Log "Post Command Output: $postOutput"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Log "Error occurred during posting: $_"
    }
}

# Replace "Pending item" with "Completed" in all text files in the execution folder after posting XML files
Replace-TextInFiles -directoryPath $exemptionRequestsSubFolder -searchText "Pending item" -replaceText "Completed"

Write-Log "Script execution for pending files completed."


Logs:
2024-09-03 20:36:55 Extracted FixletID: 360809
2024-09-03 20:36:55 Extracted ExemptionRequest: RITM1375014
2024-09-03 20:36:55 Found 'Pending item' file: E:\BES Tools\Exemption_Requests\20240827-1957\20240827-1957.txt, FixletID: 360809, ExemptionRequest: RITM1375014
2024-09-03 20:36:55 No FixletID or ExemptionRequest found in 'Pending item' file: E:\BES Tools\Exemption_Requests\20240827-1957\TargetAllDevices_20240827-1957.txt
2024-09-03 20:36:55 No FixletID or ExemptionRequest found in 'Pending item' file: E:\BES Tools\Exemption_Requests\20240827-1957\TargetDevicesList_20240827-1957.txt
2024-09-03 20:36:55 No matching completed files found for pending items. Continuing script execution.
2024-09-03 20:36:55 Skipped deletion for master XML file: E:\BES Tools\Master_Exemption_Push.xml
2024-09-03 20:36:55 Skipped deletion for master XML file: E:\BES Tools\Master_Exemption_Push_Specific_Target.xml
2024-09-03 20:36:55 Attempting to login to BigFix Server...
2024-09-03 20:36:56 Login successful.
2024-09-03 20:36:56 Command output:
2024-09-03 20:36:56 Server  : https://my.server.com:52311 User    : user Successfully logged in to server!
2024-09-03 20:36:56 Initial known sitenames: ABC_Windows2012, ABC_Windows10, ABC_Windows11, ABC_Windows2019, ABC_Windows2016, ABC_Windows2022, ABC_RHEL8, ABC_Windows2016DC, ABC_macOS, ABC_RHEL7, ABC_Windows2022DC, ABC_Windows2019DC
2024-09-03 20:36:56 Normalized known sitenames: ABC_windows2012, ABC_windows10, ABC_windows11, ABC_windows2019, ABC_windows2016, ABC_windows2022, ABC_rhel8, ABC_windows2016dc, ABC_macos, ABC_rhel7, ABC_windows2022dc, ABC_windows2019dc
2024-09-03 20:36:56 Querying sitename for fixletID 
2024-09-03 20:36:58 Failed to get the sitename. Output was empty.

Tried many logic & used extractions of variables but nothing working.

It sounds like you are not using Visual Studio Code.  If possible, install VS Code and use it to debug your code.  If your code fails when ran directly from PS, it should also fail in VS Code, You already know it fails around the line Write-Log "Querying sitename for FixletID $fixletID", so you can set a break point on that line and see what variables values are wrong.  If all looks well, trace each step forward until you find a point where a variable is wrong, then find the line that sets the variable set a break there, restart code, and continue debugging until you find the faulty line.

If you find the line that is faulty, but don't understand why, or don't understand how to fix, you can update this question or create a new question (new may be better since more eyes might see it).  Unfortunately, I, along with many others, do not have your exact setup and can't recreate your environment so we can't test the code.  Also, googling BigFix brought me to HLC Software.  It sounds like you have a paid product, and with that should be support for the product.   You may have to work with them.  As for ISE, I don't believe many people are still using it, VS Code is far better.

Never mind, I was able to fix this, Thanks @darin for the quick response.

@Vijaykhurava Feel free to use the "Your Answer" box below to post the answer :)

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest could help…
